# Windows authentication doesn't work for around 30 minutes?

Tags: windows, active-directory, iis, authentication

I have a site on IIS that uses windows auth for logins and it works 99% of the time.  But on some days there will be a period of time where logging in just won't work for around 30 minutes, it keeps popping up the prompt.

In event viewer under "Security" there's an Audit Failure error for each failed login attempt.  Here is what it says under Failure Information:

```
Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
    Status:             0xc000005e
    Sub Status:         0x0
```

There's another error that popped up under "System" but I'm not sure if it's relevant:

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller. 
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).
```

What can I do to see what the issue is?

Comment: Well, you kinda answered your own question - it could either be a Name Resolution Error (DNS) or AD Replication Error.

Comment: Having a similar issue and a reboot always fixes it. @Orphans Neither option makes sense when it comes back after a period of time and never happens for other authentication.